# Cannot build gtk on windows

Tags: gtk

I have an installation of minGW which works well for building straightfowrd C++ programs.

Now I am installing GTK, following the instructions here: http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php

I have grabbed a GTK hellow world program from here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD

but when I try to build it, using this command

```
C:\Users\James\code\smartone>gcc -o hello.exe gtk_hello_world.c -mms-bitfields
IC:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/
tk/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gtk/in
lude -IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:
gtk/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/glib-2.0
IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include -LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshe
l32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig
lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk
pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

I get these errors

```
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/gtk/lib/libgtk-3.dll.a when searching
 for -lgtk-3
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/gtk/lib/libgtk-3.dll.a when searching
 for -lgtk-3
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mi
ngw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtk-3

... etc, etc, etc
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Isn't this a 32 vs 64 bits incompatibility ?

Comment: I think you might be correct.  It looks like GTK does not work on 64bit Windows.

Comment: It should work on a 64bits platform, but you're using a 64 bits compiler. I'd say you need either to use the [64 bit version of GTK](http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php) or build using a 32 bits compiler, or build with your 64 bits compiler in 32 bits mode with gcc's [-m32 option](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html).

Comment: The -m32 option does the job.  Post as answer, and I will accept.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't post it an answer at first, because I don't know exactly why this is not possible. Furthermore, I heard about -m32 only 2 days ago for the first time, you're lucky :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a 64 bits compiler. Build with your 64 bits compiler in 32 bits mode with gcc's [-m32 option](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html).